# How do I discretize Line objects

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have a polygon object that I wish to discretize.

e.g.

```
points0 = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}
DiscretizeRegion[Line[points0]]
```

My goal is to increase the number of points between the edges using internal Mathematica functions. I have tried using Polygon, BoundaryDiscretize reigion and other functions but can't seem to get just the edge meshed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: something like `DiscretizeRegion[Line[points0], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .1}]`?

Comment: @kglr This is exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks. Do you want to do this as an answer?

Comment: Dunlop, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the maximum cell measures using the option [`MaxCellMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html):

[image]

```
DiscretizeRegion[Line[points0], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .1}] (* or *)

DiscretizeRegion[Line[points0], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .1}]
```

[image]

Use `MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .5}` to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given points0 we want to insert points so that the original interval between two point is split into n intervals:

```
n = 2;
points0 = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};
tmp = Table[#[[1]] + i (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/n, {i, 0, n - 1}] & /@ 
  Partition[points0, 2, 1]
newpts=Append[Flatten[tmp, 1], points0[[-1]]]
```

[image]